Unity Cloud DevOps: One of near-identical iOS targets fails during signing
I have one project within Unity Cloud.
This project got DevOps configured, with 2 iOS build targets set up.
These build targets are identical, same repo, same branch, with the only difference being some #Define symbols, a different Bundle ID and a different credential set.
Lets call these Bundle ID com.company.app-a and com.company.app-b, app-a and app-b for short.
The project exists for quite some time, and we wanted to make a variant for Apple's Business Manager rollout. So I created a provisioning profile for app-b, build it through Unity Cloud, and rolled it out.
Now we developed the app further, and wanted to roll out updates for both variants.
The provisioning profile for app-a expired, so I made a new one and uploaded this to Unity Cloud and attempted to build it.
However, app-a failed building. After some testing, I narrowed it down to an error that happens during signing.
I see the following in the full log in Unity Build Cloud:
[2024-05-31T13:18:20.652Z] - 7.4.5.2.7.4 - INFO: ▸ The following build commands failed:
[2024-05-31T13:18:20.652Z] - 7.4.5.2.7.4 - INFO: ▸  CodeSign /BUILD_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-gmzfqhcinhahsufpjdniccrsddzm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/UnityFramework.framework (in target 'UnityFramework' from project 'Unity-iPhone')

I tried narrowing down what is causing this, and I found that only building with BundleID app-a and it's signing credentials seems to trigger this.
I cloned the configuration of app-b, removed the #Define symbols and anything that sets it apart from app-a, and it builds successfully.
I created a new certificate in my Apple Developer account, and a new provisioning profile for app-a, but this still causes the above error.
Meanwhile, building with the signing credentials for app-b still works, I'm positive the only difference is the BundleID and the credentials.
I'm completely stumped as to why this error is occurring. Any tips on how to debug this are appreciated.
